# Why the ListView in Flutter doesn't apply height?

Tags: flutter

I have a simple code:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 60.0,),
        color: Color(0xFF24323F),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
          height: 200.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I try to change the height of a Container but It doesn't work. Why?

The result of render:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [@rémi-rousselet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8394265/r%C3%A9mi-rousselet) answer (wich you should really credit the answer for):

> You need to tell flutter how to align items if they are smaller then their parent. Or else Flutter will usually force them to fill the space

As you haven't specified anything, the first container is expanded full screen, and the green on is also expanded to fill all available space (wich is full screen minus the padding).

```
return Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 60.0,
      ),
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
        height: 200.0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

That will skrink all your widget to fit the size you defined of 200.0 + 60.0 (padding) + 60.0 (padding).

However, if you want just the inner (green) Container to be 200 height and the blueish one to be full screen, you can adapt the answer to something like this (Feel free to change the Alignemt directive to fit your need):

```
return Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      vertical: 60.0,
    ),
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
        height: 200.0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell flutter how to align items if they are smaller than their parent. Or else Flutter will usually force them to fill the remaining space.

In this case, wrapping your `Directionality` into an `Align` should do the trick.

Comment: See code posted here (and you should give credit to @Rémi-Rousselet for the answer as it's the implementation of his response)